# Finding error control capability of Hamming distance

Tags: computer-science, information-theory

I have known how to calculate the Hamming distance between two message codes. But I don't know how to get the error control capability. In one case I have hamming distance of: $$ d = 8 $$

Errors detectable = $ d-1 = 7$

Errors correctable = $(\dfrac{d}{2}-1) = 3$

I don't know to finish it off from here.

Looking at another case which had $d=6$

Error detectable = 5

Error correctable = 2

....and then it goes further to say that:

*because error control capability=5, 2-bits are used for: error correction and **3 bits for error detection**, hence d=6 is DEC+TED.*

How are these derived, precisely? How do the 3bits come about?

Comment: What do you mean by "finish it off from here"?  You have correctly stated that you can detect 7 bit errors and correct 3 bit errors in the d=8 case.  What more needs to be done? Are you asking why the number correctable is $\frac d2-1$?

Comment: @RossMillikan, it is that last specification part of the "...3bits for error detection....." etc

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they are just allocating the check bits between correction and detection.  A code with distance $d$ can correct errors up to $\lfloor \frac {d-1}2\rfloor = c$ bits.  This agrees with your expression when $d$ is even but is one half greater when $d$ is odd.  You can detect $d-1$ bit errors, so they are saying you have $c$ bits for correction and $d-1-c$ bits for detection.

Comment: Also, if you have $d-1$ erasures (i.e. you know you're missing $d-1$ bits and which positions they're in), you can correct those as well.